# How can I say that I'm in progress of become a security analyst on a headline?

Tags: word-choice, sentence

I would like to state on my LinkedIn's headline that I am in progress of become a security analyst.

How could I say it without use that sentence, because that is a sentence not a headline. I had thought on something like *Security analyst apprentice* but that sounds like if I had no experience, doesn't it?

PS: I don't know which tags assign to this question, feel free to add/remove tags more appropriate.

Comment: This question sounds like an ideal candidate for http://ell.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Or even possibly at workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Headlines don't need security analysts so much as sub-editors.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The most common term would be *Junior Security Analyst*. Once you've learnt the trade, you would refer to yourself as a *Security Analyst*, and once you are an established and competent professional, you would perhaps be a *Senior Security Analyst*.

Certainly in British English, an "apprentice" (at least outside of vocational courses and manual trades) would normally be associated with a teenager or young person working within the company for the primary reason of gaining experience.

Comment: Junior implies that you have 2-5 years of professional experience already. I haven't worked as security analyst.

Comment: @yzT: Why do you say it implies that? My company (for example) takes graduates from subjects unrelated to their new role as Juniors straight out of college. Someone with 2-5 years experience here would be disappointed if they were still a junior. Obviously this is somewhat profession dependent. For example a Junior doctor has a lot of experience compared with a junior accountant for example.

Comment: That is what I see on every job offer. When the title is *Junior ....* it likely has a requirement of minimum 2+ years of experience (work experience).

Comment: well, after four years in the business, now I can tell that this was the most accurate answer. In my own company, we call newcomers with no experience juniors as well.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps, "security analyst in training".

Answer (score 1):

I think you could quite easily title yourself as **"Trainee Security Analyst".**

Security Analyst (Rookie), is a possibility, or

Security Analyst Journeyman - but this would imply a trade in which you are trained, competent, and effective but nowhere near mastery and still effectively learning.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't write this on a LinedIn headline, but I guess you are a "soon-to-be security analyst"?